# ElasticSearch queries for Ngramm

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to make search for such case
for example i have document

```
1)"There are a lot of diesel cars in the city"
2)"Cars have diesel engines"
3)"Bob sold diesel car"
```

and I want to find doc 1 and doc 3
if I wrote such query

```
"query":
  { 
   "function_score": 
       { "query":
            {"bool":
               {"should":[
                  {"query_string": 
                     { "fields" : ["text"],
                      "query" : "\"diesel car\"~1^5"
       }}]}}}}
```

I will find doc1 but not doc3
Is it possible if i use Ngramm analyser this query will work also for doc3?

Or maybe there are other solutions?

Proximity search works only for totally exact phrases if only one character in word change then it's not work. Maybe ES have other solutions for that?

Comment: You can checkout proximity query in combination with fuziness: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/fuzziness.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

1)Use english stemmer to settings and mapping

2)Use simple query like

```
(diesel AND car)^5
```